# Keeping Local Magento Plugins In Sync With Heroku Servers

Tags: magento-connect

Locally I have the Fishpig wordpress plugin installed so I can develop our theme and some of our custom modules.

When I push to our Heroku servers (that connect to an AWS RDS database) the plugin is not listed on the Magento Connect page.

How do I keep locally installed plugins in sync with the live version?

Comment: Not answering with a simple link, but really nothing to add to this post: http://vinaikopp.com/2014/11/03/magento-setup-scripts/

Comment: @Melvyn since I don't think anyway will come up with a better solution just post the link, maybe take some snippets from it :)

Comment: @Melvyn I will likely read the whole thing but could you point out some highlights for guidance?

Comment: Will do in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments all the details are in [this post by Vinai Kopp](http://vinaikopp.com/2014/11/03/magento-setup-scripts/).

The short version: Magento only scans for new modules when the configuration cache is not present. So if you deploy new extensions to your live site, you need to build a new configuration cache. Pending the impact of the module, you may also need to refresh or flush additional caches, but the trigger is based on the configuration cache.

How to integrate this into your deployment is a different topic in it's own right and there are various methods using various tools scattered in blogs around the web, ranging from what the cool kids call "old school maintenance windows" to continuous integration methods using tools like [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) or [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/overview/what-is-capistrano/).

There's even a SAAS solution tailored to Magento called [Mageflow](https://mageflow.com/).